# Arduino Blocks at Uploading

Tags: arduino-mega, uploading, millis

I am trying to make an operating hours counter with arduino, i started with a basic script to make the arduino work as a stop watch, This is my script:

```
unsigned long start=0, finish=0, elapsed=0;

 void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Clock START");
 }
 void displayResult(unsigned long elapsed){
   float h,m,s,ms;
   unsigned long over;
   h=int(elapsed/3600000);
   over=elapsed%3600000;
   m=int(over/60000);
   over=over%60000;
   s=int(over/1000);
   ms=over%1000;
   Serial.print("Elapsed time: ");
   Serial.print(h,0);
   Serial.print("h ");
   Serial.print(m,0);
   Serial.print("m ");
   Serial.print(s,0);
   Serial.print("s ");
   Serial.print(ms,0);
   Serial.println("ms");
   Serial.println();
 }

 void loop() {
   start = millis();
   delay(200);
   Serial.println("Start");
   Serial.println("doing Operations and stuff");
   delay(800);
   finish=millis();
   elapsed=finish-start;
   Serial.println("Ended !!!");
   displayResult(elapsed);

 }
```

Unfortuantly the arduino compiler blocks at the Uploading part, i tried compiling it at first without uploading, it gave me no warning errors. I tried compiling other scripts they worked, it only blocks for this stop watch code.
Thank you for your help

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I don't get any message error, it just hangs there for 5 minuts at it just gave me :  avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

Comment: Weird. I have no problem uploading and running this on my Mega. Looks like a communication problem. What is your OS? BTW: there is no point in using float variables here.

Comment: I use windows 7, i also tried other usb ports but it just hangs for this exact script.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in early versions of the Mega2560 bootloader.  It crashes on `!!!` (or enters some other special state that stops uploading happening).

Your string that contains `!!!` will be breaking it:

```
Serial.println("Ended !!!");
```

Simple solution: don't use so many exclamation marks.